# How can I downcast to MyStruct and access method impl'd by Arc<Mutex<MyStruct>>?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to do some testing against an existing implementation, which I cannot change for the testing purposes.

For the test to work, I need to cast a `dyn Thing` into a `RealThing`.  The catch is that I receive an `Arc<Mutex<dyn Thing>>` and must call a method on `OtherTrait` which is implemented for `Arc<Mutex<RealThing>>`.

Confused yet?   yeah, so was I.

Here's a simple example with `Animal`, `Mammal`, `Horse` to illustrate more concretely:

```rust
// The goal here is to cast a dyn Animal into a Horse and
// call a method from Mammal, which is implemented by
// Arc<Mutex<Horse>.   kinda crazy, yeah?

use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

// I can't change this
pub trait Animal {

    fn identify(&self) {
        println!("I'm an animal");
    }
    
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

// I can't change this
pub trait Mammal {
    fn identify_as_mammal(&self) -> String{
        "I am a mammal".to_string()
    }
}

// I can't change this
struct Horse<G> {
    pub age: G,
}

// I can't change this
impl<G: 'static> Animal for Horse<G> {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

// I especially can't change this.
impl<G> Mammal for Arc<Mutex<Horse<G>>> {}


fn main() {

    // I can't change this.  I receive locked_dyn_animal.
    let horse: Horse<usize> = Horse { age: 10 };
    let locked_dyn_animal: Arc<Mutex<dyn Animal>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(horse));
    
    // ------  I can only change things below ------

    // Attempt 1: This doesn't compile because it creates Arc<Mutex<&Horse<usize>>> instead of Arc<Mutex<Horse<usize>>>    
    let dyn_animal = locked_dyn_animal.lock().unwrap();
    let horse_ref = <dyn Any>::downcast_ref::<  Horse<usize>  >(&dyn_animal).unwrap();
    let locked_horse = Arc::new(Mutex::new(horse_ref));

    // Attempt 2:  This also doesn't compile for the same reason.
    // let dyn_animal = locked_dyn_animal.lock().unwrap();
    // let horse_ref = dyn_animal.as_any().downcast_ref::< Horse<usize> >().unwrap();
    // let locked_horse = Arc::new(Mutex::new(horse_ref));
    
    let lg = locked_horse.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{}.  My age is {}", lg.identify_as_mammal(), lg.age);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a5551be60094090bde61b62b20b7d63)

The compile error is:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `identify_as_mammal` found for struct `MutexGuard<'_, &Horse<usize>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:60:38
   |
60 |     println!("{}.  My age is {}", lg.identify_as_mammal(), lg.age);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `MutexGuard<'_, &Horse<usize>>`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Mammal` defines an item `identify_as_mammal`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | pub trait Mammal {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

note: even if I add `impl<G> Mammal for Arc<Mutex<&Horse<G>>> {}`, I still get the same compile error.

So, is there some way to do this, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: I have an answer here that looks like it addresses your question: [How to do runtime polymorphism using Arc<Mutex<dyn SomeTrait>> in Rust?](/a/77115898/2189130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can add a `Mammal` implementation on `Horse<G>`, there is no way to do this without cloning the concrete value in the `Arc<Mutex<_>>` and creating your own `Arc<Mutex<_>>` wrapping it.

> note: even if I add `impl<G> Mammal for Arc<Mutex<&Horse<G>>> {}`, I still get the same compile error.

This should work if you invoke the trait method on `locked_horse`, but your code doesn't do this.  Your code does `lg.identify_as_mammal()` which is a `MutexGuard` that references the inner `Horse`.  Therefore, the `Arc<Mutex<&Horse<G>>>` implementation does not apply.

---

You also need to fix this line, which attempts to downcast the `MutexGuard` and not the contained value:

```
let horse_ref = <dyn Any>::downcast_ref::<  Horse<usize>  >(&dyn_animal).unwrap();
```

You need to use the `as_any` trait method here instead.

---

Fixing both of these problems, here is a working version of `main()`:

```
fn main() {
    // I can't change this.  I receive locked_dyn_animal.
    let horse: Horse<usize> = Horse { age: 10 };
    let locked_dyn_animal: Arc<Mutex<dyn Animal>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(horse));

    // ------  I can only change things below ------

    // Attempt 1: This doesn't compile because it creates Arc<Mutex<&Horse<usize>>> instead of Arc<Mutex<Horse<usize>>>
    let dyn_animal = locked_dyn_animal.lock().unwrap();
    let horse_ref = <dyn Any>::downcast_ref::<Horse<usize>>(dyn_animal.as_any()).unwrap();
    let locked_horse = Arc::new(Mutex::new(horse_ref));

    // Attempt 2:  This also doesn't compile for the same reason.
    // let dyn_animal = locked_dyn_animal.lock().unwrap();
    // let horse_ref = dyn_animal.as_any().downcast_ref::< Horse<usize> >().unwrap();
    // let locked_horse = Arc::new(Mutex::new(horse_ref));

    let lg = locked_horse.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{}.  My age is {}", locked_horse.identify_as_mammal(), lg.age);
}
```

In your actual case, this code may deadlock or panic if `identify_as_mammal` tries to take a lock as well. In that case, you need to release the lock taken to read `age` before or after calling the `identify_as_mammal` method.

For example, you could change `let lg = locked_horse.lock().unwrap();` to `let age = locked_horse.lock().unwrap().age;` and use that instead of `lg.age`.

Comment: wow, you are fast, thank-you!     Do you think it is possible to make it work without the `impl<G> Mammal for Arc<Mutex<&Horse<G>>> {}`?    Because the codebase I'm testing doesn't have that, and I'm trying to test *it*, not a modified version of it.   If it's not possible, then I guess I can say the codebase doesn't have the weakness I'm trying to demonstrate with the test that requires the cast.

Comment: @danda The first paragraph in my answer addresses that -- no, it would not be possible.

Comment: fair point.   I am accepting your answer.    Also, I discovered another way to achieve the result I was trying to do with this downcast in my real code, and indeed the downcast is not even necessary, and my test has demonstrated the weakness/flaw I thought to exist, which can now be remedied.   So, problem solved!